# Conditionally open links in a new tab

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

My goal is to make these links open in a new tab **only** if the check box is ticked.

Why is my anchor.getAttribute not a function if I change getElementByID to getElementsByClassName?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head> </head>
    <title> </title>
    <body>
        <input id="checkr" type="checkbox">Open in New Window</input>
        <br />
        <a href="http://www.google.com" class="linker">Google</a> <br>
        <a href="http://www.w3schools.com" class="linker">W3 Schools</a> <br>
        <a href="http://www.twitch.tv" class="linker">Twitch</a> <br>

        <script>
            var checkr = document.getElementById('checkr');
            var anchor = document.getElementsByClassName('linker');
            var link = anchor.getAttribute('href');

            function OpenWindow(href) {
                if (checkr.checked) {
                    window.open(href, '_blank');
                } else {
                    window.open(href, '_self');
                }
            }
            anchor.onclick = function() {
                OpenWindow(link);
                return false;
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please update your question so as to include the code, in case the link becomes unavailable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object...element*s* *plural* should be a clue...it's not returning a *single* thing, it's returning a *collection* of thing.

So to attach your handlers, you need to loop over them like so:

```
const linkers = document.getElementsByClassName('linker');
for(const linker of linkers) {
  linker.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    // this is your click event listener
  });
}
```

Second, the way you're trying to get the anchor isn't going to work, because *which anchor are you talking about*?  The best way to do it is let the event itself tell you what anchor was clicked, which it does through it's `target` property:

```
const linkers = document.getElementsByClassName('linker');
for(const linker of linkers) {
  linker.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    const href = evt.target.attributes['href'].value;
  });
}
```

Since you don't want the default behavior to happen, call `evt.preventDefault()`:

```
const linkers = document.getElementsByClassName('linker');
for(const linker of linkers) {
  linker.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const href = evt.target.attributes['href'].value;
  });
}
```

Then finally you can get the value of the checkbox and take the appropriate action:

```
const linkers = document.getElementsByClassName('linker');
for(const linker of linkers) {
  linker.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const href = evt.target.attributes['href'].value;
    const newWindow = document.getElementById('checkr').checked;
    window.open(href, newWindow ? '_blank' : '_self');
  });
}
```

Note that I'm using `for...of` loops, which may not be available in manky old browsers.  If that's a problem, you can replace them with regular `for` loops with indices (you can't use `Array#forEach` because the DOM, in its infinite wisdom [cough] doesn't return arrays, but *array-like* objects).